# What is adding the extra size to my Unity game

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here is the size report from my editor when building for iOS:

**Build Report**

Uncompressed usage by category (Percentages based on user generated assets only):

| Element | Size | % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Textures | 102.3 mb | 86.6% |
| Meshes | 0.0 kb | 0.0% |
| Animations | 22.9 kb | 0.0% |
| Sounds | 5.1 mb | 4.3% |
| Shaders | 978.1 kb | 0.8% |
| Other Assets | 907.4 kb | 0.7% |
| Levels | 1.0 mb | 0.9% |
| Scripts | 1.3 mb | 1.1% |
| Included DLLs | 6.5 mb | 5.5% |
| File headers | 109.1 kb | 0.1% |
| Total User Assets | 118.2 mb | 100.0% |
| Complete build size | 476.8 mb | - |

What I do not understand is how does it add up to the final size of 476MB. All the user assets amount to 118MB. So where does the rest come from?

My final archive from Xcode is of 470MB too.

Comment: What platform are you building for? Development build on or off?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. Is is for iOS.

Comment: This is a few years old but still relevant: https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/SamIzzo/20170717/300273/Investigating_Unity_iOS_executable_bloat.php The ipa file includes executable code that is not listed in the build report. If you are building both armv7 and arm64 then it includes two executables. If you have bitcode turned on those will be larger than normal but when recompiled by Apple for each device type will shrink quite a bit. If development build is turned on that also adds substantial overhead. Upload it to iTunes Connect and once processed you can see the download size per device.

Comment: @RetiredNinja that is indeed very detailed walkthrough. I will have to go through the article and compare the results to find out what is happening. The final size when creating an ipa file for iOS is much smaller, but it is very hard to understand that information from the editor log.